# Powershell understanding Copy-Item and foreach multiple Servers

Tags: powershell

my first post i hope i do everything right :)

What i wannt to do:

1. Get Server from a specific AD Group
2. Check if there is in the windows Error Folder an ApplicationCrash with the name xyz
3. For all the results witch are defined in the table $DestinationServer and $Folderpath i wannt them to copy to \NetworkShare\test
4. In the copy source to destination part i want to add to the foldername the Servername from where it was copied.

How can i do thath? So i get a output and i want them to copy all from the servers witch have a result to Copy to an specific network Share?

See below my script

```
$Computers = Get-ADGroupMember "ADGROUP" 
$result = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computers -ScriptBlock { Get-ChildItem C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\} | Select FullName,Parent,Name,PSComputerName,LastWriteTime | where {$_.Name -like '*Applikationname*'}
$fromPath = $result.Fullname
$foldername = $result.name
$Destinastionserver = $result.PSComputerName

foreach HOWTO ?
{
$Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName "$connectoserver"
Copy-Item "$frompath\" -Destination "\\Networkshare\test\$foldername" -ToSession $Session -Recurse
}
```

THANKS for your help

**Now i have Changed the code to:**

```
Get-ADGroupMember "ADGROUPSERVER" | Where-Object { $_.ObjectClass -eq 'Computer'} |
ForEach-Object {
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $PSItem.Name -ScriptBlock {
          Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive'} |
          Select-Object -Property FullName,
                                  Parent,
                                  Name,
                                  PSComputerName,
                                  LastWriteTime |
          where {$PSItem.Name -like '*App*'} |
          Select-Object -Property Fullname,
                                  name,
                              PSComputerName
} |
ForEach {
    $Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $PSItem.PsComputername
    Copy-Item "$PSItem.FullName" -Destination "\\server\share\folder\$($PSitem.PSComputerName)" -ToSession $Session -Recurse -WhatIf
}
```

**I am getting this error, why is there a :string after Servername?**

```
Copy-Item : The path '\\server\share\folder\SERVERNAME' is not valid. Only absolute paths are supported on remote copy operations.
At line:19 char:5
Copy-Item "$PSItem.FullName" -Destination "\\server\share ...
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (\\server\share\Data\SERVERNAME:String) [Copy-Item], ArgumentException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : RemotePathIsNotAbsolute,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
```

Comment: `Get-ADGroupMember` does not only return computer objects, but also users and groups. You need to make sure you use only computer objects by adding a `Where-Object` clause: `$Computers = Get-ADGroupMember "ADGROUP" | Where-Object { $_.objectClass -eq 'computer' }`

Comment: Thank you i have take the change over :)

Answer (score 0):

If I am following what you have posted, maybe, just maybe, this refactor (untested and off the top of my head) should help point you in the right direction.

Remember, that in the remote sessions, variables have scope. So, if they are not being seen, then you need to deal with variable scope, by say using the `$Using` modifier.

This formatting is not required, it's just my way of making things more readable for my old eyes.  ***;-}***
All have their preferences of course.

```
Get-ADGroupMember 'ADGROUP"' | 
ForEach-Object {
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $PSItem.Name -ScriptBlock { 
          Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive'} | 
          Select-Objeft -Property FullName, 
                                  Parent, 
                                  Name, 
                                  PSComputerName, 
                                  LastWriteTime | 
          where {$PSItem.Name -like '*Applikationname*'} | 
          Select-Object -Property Fullname,
                                  name,
                                  PSComputerName
} | 
ForEach {
    $Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $connectoserver
    Copy-Item -Path $PSItem.FullName -Destination "\\Networkshare\test\$($PSitem.PSComputerName)" -ToSession $Session -WhatIf
}
```

Update as per your comment

As per the Copy-Item docs

```
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/copy-item?view=powershell-7.1


# Example 5: Copy a file to a remote computer
$Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName "Server01" -Credential "Contoso\User01"
Copy-Item "D:\Folder001\test.log" -Destination "C:\Folder001_Copy\" -ToSession $Session


# Example 6: Copy a folder to a remote computer
$Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName "Server02" -Credential "Contoso\User01"
Copy-Item "D:\Folder002\" -Destination "C:\Folder002_Copy\" -ToSession $Session


# Example 7: Recursively copy the entire contents of a folder to a remote computer
$Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName "Server04" -Credential "Contoso\User01"
Copy-Item "D:\Folder003\" -Destination "C:\Folder003_Copy\" -ToSession $Session -Recurse
```

Yet, the destination must already exist. You have to create that in advance or force the creation on the copy, using the `-Force` switch/parameter.

```
New-Item -Path "\\Networkshare\test\$($PSitem.PSComputerName)"
Copy-Item -Path $PSItem.FullName -Destination "\\Networkshare\test\$($PSitem.PSComputerName)" -ToSession $Session -WhatIf

# Or 

Copy-Item -Path $PSItem.FullName -Destination "\\Networkshare\test\$($PSitem.PSComputerName)" -ToSession $Session -Force -WhatIf

Copy-Item
    [-Path] <String[]>
    [[-Destination] <String>]
    [-Container]
    [-Force]
    [-Filter <String>]
    [-Include <String[]>]
    [-Exclude <String[]>]
    [-Recurse]
    [-PassThru]
    [-Credential <PSCredential>]
    [-WhatIf]
    [-Confirm]
    [-FromSession <PSSession>]
    [-ToSession <PSSession>]
    [<CommonParameters>]
```

Comment: First of all thank you so much for your time :)

I changed 

From: $Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $connectoserver
To: $Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $PSItem.PSCompuername

But i am getting the error in the Part Copy-Item thath the Path musst be absolute any ideas on this?

Comment: hm ok i googled a bit looks like with your example we are running in a Double Hop issue? Session 1 is invoking Session 2 are the sessions.I tried with PSSessionKonfiguration but i think this is a bit complicated.

Comment: Not really my example, but your use case. Remember, all I did was refactor your code, not change your use case. Double-hop is a thing, PowerShell notwithstanding. It's a Windows authentication boundary, not a PowerShell-specific issue. Dealing with DH, is a well discussed/demo'd topic for all things including the PS use case. [This is a detail of just one](https://www.travisgan.com/2014/03/enable-powershell-double-hop-remoting.html#:~:text=When%20working%20with%20PowerShell%2C%20there%20are%20cases%20when,and%20there%20are%20two%20servers%2C%20server1%20and%20server2). You have to set it up.

Comment: Yeah sorry it was my script but i am new to this.Sorry for my english.Could you help me or rewrite it i want to use it without credssp or maybe fhere is another way ?